# Update with earliest date in same SQL column

Tags: sql, self-join

I need to make updates to a table where I update the Order_Date column to a customer's earliest order date. All of the records associated that that customer must be updated to that earliest date. Date is in YYYYMMDD format.

My starting table looks something like this:

### CUSTOMER_ID         Order_Date

```
        1           20170101
        1           20180101
        2           20190101 
        2           20200101
        2           20210101
        3           20170101
```

The updated table needs to look like this:

### CUSTOMER_ID         Order_Date

```
        1           20170101
        1           20170101
        2           20190101 
        2           20190101
        2           20190101
        3           20170101
```

I've been trying to figure this out with a self join. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Order_Date is a varchar that works with min. I'm using Toad for Oracle

Comment: Please, specify your DBMS with appropriate tag, because update of subquery is not possible in every DBMS. Also please show your current code and describe what is the issue with it.

Comment: Could you please mark my answer as the solution? Since it worked, I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
UPDATE CUSTOMER c 
SET ORDER_DATE=(SELECT MIN(CAST(ORDER_DATE as DATE))
     FROM CUSTOMER c2 
     WHERE c2.CUSTOMER_ID=c.CUSTOMER_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you can apply update....from form. For example;

```
UPDATE TableName SET Order_Date = T.Order_Date
FROM (
    SELECT Customer_Id, MIN(CAST(Order_Date AS DATE)) as Order_Date 
    FROM TableName
    GROUP BY Customer_Id
) AS T
WHERE Customer_Id = T.Customer_Id
```

Look at the query. I select customer_id and order_date with group by. Also as you can see i add an aggregate function for order_date column which is "min". It selects the earliest date.